# Python OOP - How to make variables that refer to keys in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {1: {2: 'A'}, 2: {3: 'B'}, 3: {4: 'C}}
```

I want to make variables in string form, called markers, that can refer to nested keys.
For example: `'mymarker'` refers to my `my_dict[1][2]`, and `'myothermarker'` refers to `my_dict[2][3]`.
They are strings so I can assign them in one of my methods, for example: set_marker('mymarker', 1, 2). How can I implement this into my code?

Comment: You'll have to say more about what these markers need to be able to do.  Why are they strings?

Comment: They are strings so I can assign them in one of my methods, for example: set_marker('mymarker', 1, 2)

Answer (score 1):

There's not way to do exactly what you want directly, since the nested dictionary doesn't take just one key to get to an inner value. You need several keys. But you could store several keys together if you want, in a tuple, perhaps. Then you could use the values in either a loop (if you're not always indexing to the same depth) or by unpacking (if you are).

Try something like this:

```
my_dict = {1: {2: 'A'}, 2: {3: 'B'}, 3: {4: 'C'}}
mymarker = (1, 2)
myothermarker = (2, 3)

a, b = mymarker     # you can use unpacking when you know you're indexing to a specific depth
print(my_dict[a][b])

d = my_dict
for key in myothermarker:    # or use a loop, for indexing to any depth
    d = d[key]
print(d)
```

You've commented that you want your "marker" values to be strings, that you pass in to a `set_marker` function along with the keys, and then later you can call `set_with_marker` to modify the value referred to by the keys in the main dictionary. That is not too hard to combine with the techniques I describe above, you just need an extra layer of indirection to go between the string markers and the keys they refer to.

Here's a quick, untested implementation that should do what you want:

```
markers = {}
def set_marker(name, *keys):
    markers[name] = keys       # save the keys into the markers dict (as lists)

def get_with_marker(name):
    d = my_dict
    for key in markers[name]:  # this is almost the same as the loop from above
        d = d[key]
    return d

def set_with_marker(name, value):
    *keys, last = markers[name] # unpack last name separately from the others
    d = my_dict
    for key in keys: # this is similar to before, but we don't index the last level yet
        d = d[key]
    d[last] = value  # we index the last level here, for the assignment
```

You may want these functions to be methods of some class (with `my_dict` being an instance attribute). Other than adding `self` in a bunch of places, it doesn't significantly change the code.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, didnt think of tuples. Is there a way to have the markers as strings, as I need multiple markers to refer to different keys

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The keys in the dictionary are numbers, so you need to get numbers from somewhere. Maybe use a dictionary mapping from your "marker" strings to tuples of keys?

Comment: I have a setter method that works as follows: set_marker('markergoeshere', 1, 2), I need to be able to do this for multiple markers. The marker should be able to return 'A', and I should be able to change 'A' to a different value

Comment: You can write such a function, but I'm not sure what you mean by "the marker should be able to return 'A'". The marker is just a string, it doesn't "return" anything. Are you passing it to another method, after setting it up with `set_marker`? All this stuff should have been in the question, if you wanted help with it.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information in the question, and yes I would be passing it into another method. For example, set_by_marker('mymarker', 'B') should change 'A' to 'B'.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you, this is genius. I haven't learned some of these concepts yet but they really helped. Thanks again